# Can't upload trial app to iPhone for testing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, version, development-environment

I guess my iPhone has too recent a version so my app won't upload to my phone? Here's the screen I see:
[image: xcode organizer view]

I want to test my app on my phone but I don't know how to change the version and if I do change the version, if it will screw up everything I have on my phone now. I'm pretty sure my provisioning profiles and all that are in order, it seems like just the version is preventing me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to upgrade Xcode to the newest version (4.3.2), and download the iOS 5.1 library within Xcode. In doing so, Xcode will then recognize iOS 5.1 as an actual system.**  This version of Xcode was released before iOS 5.1.

As always, update Xcode through the Mac App Store.

Comment: I have Xcode 4.2.1 with no new updates available according to the mac app store.

Comment: 4.3.2 is the latest version. Download it from the Mac App Store or from the Developer Portal and you should be good to go

Comment: Yeah you don't have the latest version. If there is nothing in the Updates section, just redownload Xcode from its page in the App Store.

Comment: Yeah you should be! Just make sure to download the iOS 5.1 library (see my original answer)